# Is it possible to use the RMAH with paypal without texting?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

I have a PayPal account and a credit card, but I don't have texting. Is it possible to use the real money auction house without it?

Comment: Those who wish to use PayPal™ (available in certain regions) to buy items or receive the proceeds of their auctions will need to sign up for our Battle.net SMS Protect service. Out of luck I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use the RMAH without texting, you just need the Blizzard authenticator app. Whether you can download the money to Paypal or not is a different story, but you can do other things with the money, for example exchange the money in RMAH to gold and buy gear.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**; no you do not *need* SMS protect to use the Real Money Auction House, but some features relating to your Battle.net balance and PayPal may be unavailable - like cashing out your balance.

**Long answer**;
I do not use the Battle.net SMS protect service but I do have the Battle.net mobile authenticator application installed on my iDevice:

[image: Battle.net Account Security]

To date I have performed the following Battle.net Balance/Real Money Auction House actions, and have not once been asked to sign up for the Battle.net SMS Protect service;

- sold items on the Diablo III Real Money Auction House,
- purchased an item on the Diablo III Real Money Auction House,
- topped up my Battle.net balance using a debit card transaction,
- used my Battle.net balance to purchase character services for World of Warcraft.

With this in mind, I am unsure what restrictions not using Battle.net SMS protect applies to your account. The [Battle.net FAQ for SMS protect](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battlenet-sms-protect) says that this service is provided for the following features;

- unlock your Battle.net account using your mobile phone,
- remove an unwanted authenticator from your account,
- recover your account name,
- reset your password.

Personally I have never used PayPal with my Battle.net account, however, this [page from the Blizzard FAQs regarding PayPal](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/syncing-paypal-with-battlenet) indicates that signing up to Mobile Alerts is required to 'sync' your Battle.net account with PayPal, in order to use PayPal to top up your Battle.net balance, or purchase value added services from Blizzard (like RMAH or account customisation services for WoW) using PayPal.

Comment: it only requires you to hook up your SMS if you want to be able to directly sell from the RMAH to your paypal account (at the same time incuring a 15% transaction fee)

Comment: and afaik paypal is the only way you can get money out from your battle.net account by selling straight to paypal.  If you ever somehow incur over 250$ in your battle.net account, you will not have access to that extra amount.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Google voice account and use the SMS features which allow for free texting in the United States. 
According to [this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/receive-and-send-free-sms-text-messanges-in-google-gmail-chat/) link, it doesn't sounds like you need a current texting plan. You simply would provide your Google voice to Blizzard and you would receive a text back via chat.

I have not tried this, but it seems like it may work.

Comment: you cannot do this, the SMS features cannot work with VOIP numbers.

Comment: Its even worse if you have a regular cell #, there's a chance its in the VOIP directory and blizzard will think its a VOIP number even though its not.  The chances of this depends on the service provider and whether or not its a prepaid phone.  One of my friends has a prepaid phone and can't link up paypal to rmah without getting a new phone number.

Comment: @yx So no online texting service would work? I am assuming all online texting services are VOIP.

Comment: it has to do with whether or not the number appears in some VoIP database.  If its a VOIP number it won't work no matter what, which is extremely stupid and frustrating.  Given the way numbers get recycled all the time now its a crap shoot whether or not it works.